# Argument Exception - Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I am trying to get a column value from a SharePoint list and populate it to an ASP text box. I used `SPQuery` to filter and get the value. I even mentioned view fields and increased the List View Lookup Threshold. But when I am trying to assign the text box value with the column field, I am getting this exception:

> Argument exception was unhandled by user- value does not fall within the expected range.

Is there any workaround for this? Code sample:

```
SPQuery qrySeriesDesc = new SPQuery();
qrySeriesDesc.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Series'/><Value Type='Text'>" + SeriesNumber + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
qrySeriesDesc.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Series Description'/>";
SPListItemCollection itemCol = list.GetItems(qrySeriesDesc);
foreach (SPListItem item in itemCol)
{
    if (item != null)
    {
        tboxSeriesDescription.Text = item["Series Description"].ToString();            
    }
}
```

I am getting the mentioned exception at:

```
tboxSeriesDescription.Text = item["Series Description"].ToString();
```

Comment: take a look on http://www.ashokraja.me/tips/How-to-resolve-Error-Value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range-with-Exception-Microsoft-SharePoint-SPFieldMap-GetColumnNumber

Answer (score 0):

Try to get it from field, not from item:

```
        SPField fieldSerDesc = item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("SeriesDescription"); //internal name of your fields. Usually eq StaticName.
        tboxSeriesDescription.Text = item[fieldSerDesc.Id].ToString();
```

Or, if your field is lookup for example, you can do it like this:

```
        SPFieldLookup fieldSerDesc = (SPFieldLookup)item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("SeriesDescription");
        tboxSeriesDescription.Text = fieldSerDesc.GetFieldValueAsText(item[fieldSerDesc.Id]);
    }
```

Comment: I tried the above snippet and am getting the same exception.

Comment: Is there some extra info in callstack when exception raised?

Comment: By the way, your field Name contains spaces, but what about  InternalName? Do you set InternalName manually? If not, it equals "Series_x0020_Description". Try to put it in your query and in the item selector.

Comment: No just the exception message and I tried using the internalName "Series_x0020_Description". I am getting the same exception message.

Comment: That's strange. Can you provide your ContentType definition?

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because the field do not exist or is misspelled.

Please note that if you select a column that does not exist SharePoint does not raise any error.

Try to check the field's name using a tool like [Sharepoint Manager](https://spm.codeplex.com/) and use ALWAYS the internal name

Comment: The field exists in the list and I have given the correct internal name of the field which I checked using SharePoint Manager.

Comment: Try to remove the **<where>** clausole and the **ViewFields** maybe the result is empty. You can also use a tool, like [spcamlquery](https://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/) for execute the query